# How can I display a message before login only on the next login?

Tags: linux, login

Background:

I have a virtual machine image running Linux Mint that I am distributing to multiple users.  The first time they boot the VM, it takes a long time for Tomcat to load as the applications it runs do some first-run processing*, and I want to warn users of that.  However, Tomcat loads quickly on subsequent boots, so I don't want the warning message on later boots, only some basic system information.

I already have a pre-login message using /etc/issue .  Is there a good way to display a modified pre-login message only once?  I know I can do a post-login message with a script, but the way the VM is set up users don't usually log in, so they'd never see it.

*Shipping the VM with the first-run processing already done would increase the size of the VM by about 50%, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Have the Tomcat processes replace `/etc/issue` with a non-warning version when they've finished (assuming you can include some of your own processing in those scripts).

Or, have any script (`/etc/rc.local`?) run which replaces `/etc/issue` after everything has finished booting.

Comment: I can't do that, but I bet I can make a script that just replaces /etc/issue after everything boots once, which is good enough for my purposes - thanks.